# Send Private message to facebook user throw android application

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, xmpp

I saw that I can't send castum private message through the Facebook API:
[#How to send message facebook friend through graph api using Accessstoken](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken)

and then I saw this solution:
[#Message via chat API](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/35-how-to-send-private-messages-with-facebook-api)

That allows you to send message through the Chat API. but this solution is for ruby on rails only.

Can someone show me how to do it in Java/Android code? or knows how to send message Via Jabber/XMPP service from android.